# Advanced Session Script

Tags: php

I was wondering if anybody knows how to make a script that would essentially save a percentage of how much you completed of say a test or something and when you go back to continue it will bring you to the page you're at. For example theres 5 pages, and you're on page 3 so it'll save as 60% and whenever you click continue it brings you to that page.

When I say advanced I mean like secure so you can't go skip to page 5 just by putting the url. For example at the head of each test page I would put this

```
if (session > 60%) {
header(Location: page3);
}
```

Do you guys know what I mean?

I was hoping somebody could just help me do this somehow and make it so it saves under the users profile and you can call the percentage whenever using a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW a database is a fine solution, and (for small workflows that don't need to be durable) session would be fine too. You are correct to care that people can break the flow by tampering with the query string. You probably need to [read up on getting/setting values in session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and then you'll know what to do (or can ask a proper question).

Comment: Thankyou @TimMedora from your link it showed sorta what I could do. Atleast now I understand what I would have to do but it wouldn't be as simple as that. I'll try to read more on that page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. First, check out any [PHP Session Tutrorial](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm) to learn about them a bit.

You can access session variables with $_SESSION['keyname'] (after you've called session_start() on your page.

Simply save your progress as one of these, e.g. `$_SESSION['progress'] = 60;`

and evaluate by testing if the session is set (so you don't get an error), and then evaluate it as follows:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['progress']) )
{
    //write your if (or switch) statement here
}
```

Let me know if that makes sense or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Now just say I wanted to save it under each users profile I should just make a new value in the database called "example1" for example and then make it save $_SESSION as the value of "example1".

Do you think that would work at all? Or would there be an easier way.

Comment: Lol then @RPM [was right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883865/advanced-session-script#comment27871505_18883865): use a database. Save your user and their progress to the database, store the user in the session, and then use that to retrieve the user from the database and retrieve their progress..

Comment: Yes but that wasn't exactly what my question was at all really. The point is that is all really easy. I'm asking how I would make it invulnerable so that it would check the database for what percentage you have completed and then it will redirect you to a certain page depending on that. I was asking what people thought would be the easiest way to make it secure and the most efficient.